# Prove that $\{\sin x, \sin 2x, ... , \sin nx\}$ is a linearly independent set

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-series, lp-spaces

> Prove that $\{\sin x, \sin 2x, ... , \sin nx\}$ is linearly independent.

The short solution that I do not understand is as follow:
For p and q are positive integer, we have 
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\sin{px}\sin{qx} dx=\left\{\begin{array}{l}0\qquad  \textrm{if } \, p\ne q\\
\dfrac{\pi}{2}\qquad \textrm{if }\, p=q\ne0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Applying this result to show that if $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_k\sin kx=0$ then $\alpha_k=0,\, k=1,\dots,n$

The solution is too short for me too understand. I would be grateful if you could explain this problem more in detail for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an arbitrary linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_{i}\sin{p_ix}=0$.Multiply the sum with $\sin{p_jx}$ and integrate the outcome between $0$ and $\pi$. One gets

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i\int_0^{\pi}\sin{p_ix}\sin{p_jx}dx=\alpha_j\frac{\pi}{2}=0$$

$j$ being arbitrary, This means all $\alpha_i=0$ and the family is independant