# How to prove that {$\sin(x) , \sin(2x) , \sin(3x) ,...,\sin(nx)$} is independent in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Prove that {$\sin(x) , \sin(2x) , \sin(3x) ,...,\sin(nx)$} is independent in $\mathbb{R}$

my trial :

we know that the Wronsekian shouldn't be $0$ to get the trivial solution and thus they are independent. its not trivial to show that $ W \not = 0$

W =

\begin{vmatrix}
(1)\sin(x) & (1)\sin(2x) & (1)\sin(3x) &  ... &   (1)\sin(nx) \\
(1)\cos(x) & (2)\cos(2x) & (3)\cos(3x) &  ... &   (n)\cos(nx) \\ 
-(1)^2\sin(x) & -(2)^2\sin(2x) & -(3)^2\sin(3x) &  ... &   -(n)^2\sin(nx) \\
-(1)^3\cos(x) & -(2)^3\cos(2x) & -(3)^3\cos(3x) &  ... &   -(n)^3\cos(nx) \\
\end{vmatrix}

and so on. it looks like Vandermonde matrix but i cant prove that and so we conclude that its $W\not =0$

Comment: Note that $\LaTeX$ commands $\sin$ `\sin` and $\cos$ `\cos` for future reference.

Comment: thanks i updated it

Comment: this is ODE class i don't know whats the topic there but it doesn't like ODE class

Comment: @MartinR And of course that one deserves closure as well

Comment: @Mather Why does it matter what class the question was asked in?

Comment: i am not familiar with the material / answer they gave ,

Comment: @Mather The answer I have given does not use any theorem. It is extremely elementary.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: Here is another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1193432/42969.

Comment: thank you , the thing is i am trying to prove that through the Wronsekian ,  that it is not equal to $ 0 $ and so they are independant

Comment: @Mather The answer in the original question only requires knowledge of integrals and trigonometric functions. It is objectively simpler than any answer with Wronski determinants.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sum_{j=1}^{n} c_j \sin (jx)$=0  for all $x$ you can prove that each $c_k=0$ by multiplying both sides by $\sin(kx)$ and and integrating from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. Use the fact that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin(jx)\sin (kx)\, dx =0$ if $j \neq k$. This proves the stronger result that the sequence is independent on $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before ...

Comment: thank you but is there an answer related to ODE and wronsekian

Comment: @Mather please emphasize in your question that you would like a Wronsekian oriented answer.

Comment: the solution is simple as they mentioned above , yet the integral above proves that they are independent only in $ [-\pi,\pi] $ right ? can we do that for $\Re$  in a similar way ?

Comment: @Mather Independent on a subset of $\mathbb  R$ implies indepedence on all of $\mathbb  R$.